# Error on play my app from developer.android

Tags: android

i'm new on Android

The Android Studio give me a fail when I try to run my app from

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

The fail text is:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0] C:\Users\Spluaks\AndroidStudioProjects\HolaMundo\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-appindexing\8.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.appindexing" to force usage

Someone know?

Comment: go to your manifest file and update the minimum version of android sdk, AND at your build.gradle file update the minimum gradle version to 9

Answer (score 0):

**Change your SDK minSdkVersion 8 to 9** !! nothing else

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0** uses minimum sdk to 9, but you app is using minimum sdk 8.

***Solution: ***

Go to your `/app/build.gradle` and change `minSdkVersion` to 9.